# Can I use IF in an SQL sentence in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers

```
UPDATE `order` SET `status` = IF `type` = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END IF;
```

I wrote this sentence in a **MySQL** **trigger**, and I got this error prompt:

Error Code: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`type` = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END IF at line 5

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `CASE`:

```
UPDATE `order` 
SET    `status` = CASE WHEN `type` = 2 
                       THEN 1 
                       ELSE 2 
                  END;
```

Comment: Yes! It perfectly solves my problem. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) not [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html):

```sql
UPDATE `order`
SET `status` = IF(`type` = 2, 1, 2);
```